# Best case of pairwise comparisons of an array with 6 elements, using quicksort

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, quicksort

I am analysing the following question:

> #### Question 5B
>
> Assume that you use quicksort to sort an array with 6 elements, and use the first element as pivot. How many pairwise comparisons will be made...
>
> a) ...in the worst case? *Answer: 15 (5+4+3+2+1) and 20 (6+5+4+3+2) are accepted*
>
> b) ...in the worst case? *Answer: 8 (5+2+1), 10 (6+3+1) and 11 (6+3+2) are accepted*

I am trying to understand the answer "8 (5+2+1)". I can't visualize a  best case of 8 comparisons. If the array for example is [4,1,2,3,5,6] (pivot is 4), it checks 1-6, 2-6, 3-6, 5-6 and then swap 5 and 4 and then there are two subarrays [1,2,3] and [5,6] which has 2 and 1 comparisons?

Can someone please give an example and show how the best case can be 8 comparisons?

I tried different orders and searched on the web...

Comment: Please point to which version of QuickSort this question is about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Lomuto's Quicksort algorithm, using the leftmost value as pivot value, we can get as low as 8 comparisons for an array like [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6].

In the first iteration all values will be compared with the pivot 3 (5 comparisons), and the pivot will be moved: swapped with 2, and we get:

```
[2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6]
```

The deeper run will have the left partition [2, 1], where only 1 comparison is needed, and the pivot 2 will move to where the 1 is.

The right partition [5, 4, 6] will need 2 comparisons and put the pivot value 5 in the middle.

That leaves us with partitions that have size 1, so no comparisons occur.

Here is a JavaScript implementation of that Lomuto Quicksort algorithm, which perofrms the sort for the above mentioned array and outputs the most relevant actions to confirm 8 comparisons are needed:

```js
// Lomuto algorithm, with pivot at left side
function quickSort(arr, low, high) {

    function partition(arr, low, high) {
        let count = 0;
        const pivot = arr[low];
        let i = low;
        for (let j = low + 1; j <= high; j++) {
            count++; // Count next comparison
            console.log("compare", arr[j], "with pivot", pivot);
            if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
                i++;
                console.log("set partition index at", i);
                if (i < j) {
                    console.log("swap index", i, "with index", j);
                    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
                    console.log("swap result: ", ...arr);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log("swap pivot", pivot, "with partition index", i);
        [arr[i], arr[low]] = [arr[low], arr[i]];
        console.log("swap result: ", ...arr);
        return [i, count];
    }
    if (low >= high) return 0;
    
    const [i, count] = partition(arr, low, high);
    return count + quickSort(arr, low, i - 1) + quickSort(arr, i + 1, high);
}

const arr = [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6];
console.log("INITIAL:", ...arr);
const count = quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
console.log("SORTED:", ...arr);
console.log("COMPARISONS:", count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with:

```
4 6 3 1 5 2
```

|- -        |

Here I'm using - - to show what will be compared next, and the | | is to show the range that we're trying to split on the pivot.

After comparison 1.

```
4 2 3 1 5 6
```

|- -      |

After comparison 2.

```
2 4 3 1 5 6
 |- -    |
```

After comparison 3.

```
2 3 4 1 5 6
   |- -  |
```

After comparison 4.

```
2 3 1 4 5 6
     |- -|
```

After comparison 5.  We now have 2 ranges.

```
2 3 1 4 5 6
```

|- -  | |- -|

After comparisons 6 and 7.

```
2 1 3 4 5 6
```

|- -|

After comparison 8.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And that is how quicksort sorts this with just 8 comparisons.

Comment: It looks like the first action involves the *rotation* of `6 2 1 3 5` to `2 1 3 5 6`. Which quickSort variant does that?

Comment: @trincot It is what happens when I write it up, decide to have a more interesting array, and don't correct it properly.  Now it is fixed.